# SDWebImage/Parse Apple Mach O-Link error

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, sdwebimage

I'm getting 201 Apple Mach-O Link errors while using Parse and the SDWebImage framework. The app runs fine on my phone, but when using the simulator, I get the errors. Here's what I've imported and the errors I'm getting:

[image: Fraemworks]

Comment: Please add code/errors into question and not on pasteboards - just removed a dead link from your post just now.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar issue. Try this:

- Go to the scheme manager (top left hand corner immediately to the right of the build/stop build buttons
- Click on "New Scheme"
- Add a new scheme with your desired name

Alternatively, you could modify the scheme instead of creating a new (deleting and re-adding)

Comment: have you tried, removing and adding the framework files again?

Comment: yep! It works perfectly fine on my phone. I even tested it on another phone. But it won't work on the simulator